# semaphore in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a stored procedure in sql to take a number from table.
it has lots on records which has only column.
whenever a call it , is should take the first record and return it after that delete the record.
it works properly when we have just one thread,the problem appears when I use multithreading in my program and the procedure return the duplicate number.
the procedure is like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSubscribeNo] @Sbs_Type    INT,
                                       @subscribeNo INT OUTPUT
AS
  BEGIN
      SET @subscribeNo = -1;

      BEGIN TRAN T1;

      UPDATE UNIT_SBS_NOS
      SET    Free_SBS_NO = Free_SBS_NO
      WHERE  Sbs_Trf_Type = @Sbs_Type;

      SELECT @subscribeNo = (SELECT TOP(1) FREE_SBS_NO
                             FROM   UNIT_SBS_NOS WITH(nolock)
                             WHERE  Sbs_Trf_Type = @Sbs_Type);

      DELETE FROM UNIT_SBS_NOS
      WHERE  FREE_SBS_NO = @subscribeNo;

      INSERT INTO All_Subscribe
                  (Subscribe_No)
      VALUES      (@subscribeNo);

      COMMIT TRAN T1;
  END
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? It looks like SQL Server.

Comment: What is the purpose of `SET    Free_SBS_NO = Free_SBS_NO`?

Comment: yes,Its SQL Server!

Comment: "SET Free_SBS_NO = Free_SBS_NO" I use this to lock the records to avoid accessing other threads to get duplicate numbers

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UNIT_SBS_NOS](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [OBJ_VERSION] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
 [FREE_SBS_NO] [numeric](7, 0) NOT NULL,
 [SBS_TRF_TYPE] [numeric](1, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PKUNITSBSNOS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED )

Comment: "UNIT_SBS_NOS" is table which I inserted lots of number in column "FREE_SBS_NO" according to sequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally your current code shouldn't allow two concurrent transactions to process the same `@Sbs_Type` simultaneously.

Two concurrent threads can't both acquire `U` locks on the rows matching `WHERE Sbs_Trf_Type = @Sbs_Type`.

If two threads simultaneously call `GetSubscribeNo` with the same `@Sbs_Type` when there are *no* matching rows whilst meanwhile a third transaction inserts a row for that `@Sbs_Type` I can see how this would fail however.

One or both of the `GetSubscribeNo` calls would need to get past the `UPDATE` statement before the insert and thus fail to lock anything that would block the other one.

A better way of doing this anyway would be [with the `OUTPUT` clause](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSubscribeNo] @Sbs_Type    INT,
                                       @subscribeNo INT OUTPUT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Out TABLE (Subscribe_No INT);

      SET XACT_ABORT ON;
      BEGIN TRAN T1;

      WITH T
           AS ((SELECT TOP(1) *
                FROM   UNIT_SBS_NOS WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
                WHERE  Sbs_Trf_Type = @Sbs_Type))
      DELETE FROM T
      OUTPUT DELETED.FREE_SBS_NO INTO @Out;

      /*Default to -1 if no rows*/
      SELECT @subscribeNo = ISNULL(MAX(Subscribe_No), -1)
      FROM   @Out

      INSERT INTO All_Subscribe
                  (Subscribe_No)
      VALUES      (@subscribeNo);

      COMMIT TRAN T1;
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across his question on accident. For some reason I'm compelled to explain why this issue has occurred as it will build a strong database architecture concept as well as a better understanding of programming logic.

Deletes in SQL server are sequential/serial. You cannot multi-thread deletes for many reasons.

Rough example: thread one "delete from tblX where tblX.ID = @myVar" if you fire off 2 threads, they will "step on each other's toes". Layman's terms: one piece of pie, you and a friend want it, you both go for it, ends up bloody.

*Note: this is an over simplification, but hopefully you get the point.